# How to distribute Image and child elements evenly using flex box?

Tags: css, image, react-native, flexbox

I'm adding an Image and a number of text inputs (FloatLabelTextInput) to a `<View>` within a react-native app. So far I'm not having much luck spacing the image and text inputs evenly on the y-axis with the `flex` property.
As the image is displayed too small in height and the remaining FloatLabelTextInput take up too much height on the y-axis.

I've tested and mocked up the app's view in the Expo react-native sandbox for reference here with the same CSS I use:

- 1 Image cut off and text input take up too much height:
  https://snack.expo.io/rydGFtHQG
- 2 Image displayed correctly but ext inputs take up too much height:
  https://snack.expo.io/HyS1VYU7f

I did try setting the flex attribute as a fraction of the overall flex also,
but this doesn't adjust the width or height of the element spacing in the view.

**Question:**

How can you distribute Image and child elements evenly using flex box?

**Proposed Layout:** (This is the layout I'm aiming for, Image takes up full View width and 40% height displaying full image, while three TextInputs below the Image take up a further 40% with heights of 20px)

[image]

**What is rendered:** (This is what is rendered with this layout style, Image takes up about 10% of View and is cut off. While remaining three TextInputs take up about 50% of View and about 50px in height each which is too high for this layout.

[image]

**View style definition:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:"column",
    //alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },
  image: {
    flex: 2/4,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
  },
  floatLabelTextInput: {
    flex: 2/4,
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: don't ask me why, but it seems like flexDirection: 'row' did the thing :-O

Comment: I did try flex direction:'row' previously but that causes the image and text boxes to appear in one row on my physical device.

Comment: I think Ian Mundy has identified the main problem below. You have to set the `flex` property for image to 1 to work around this. Also, I would suggest setting `width: auto` and removing the `height` property for the image. Result: https://snack.expo.io/r1BKq-Umz (uses a different image).

Comment: If you use a regular `TextInput` instead of a `FloatLabelTextInput` you won't have these problems. E.g., https://snack.expo.io/SyxtAWIQf .

Comment: @DavidCollins using `width:auto` and `flex: 1` gives the correct proportions on the Image, but the FloatLabelTextInput input directly below take up too much height and are not spaced. I'm looking for a set height for eg, 30px each on the inputs. But specifying a height on the inputs has no effect on their height - https://snack.expo.io/BkPs1FLmM

Comment: @BrianJ: In that case I think you will need to revert to wrap the `FloatLabelTextInput` components in `View`s, and avoid using `flex` on the child components.

Comment: Is this similar to what you had in mind? https://snack.expo.io/BJAlhYImM

Comment: Yes that seems like an option wrapping each input in a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I get what you're trying to achieve here, but looking at that 2/4 image and 2/4 textinput, and from this line `So far I'm not having much luck spacing the image and text inputs evenly on the y-axis`
I believe you want the image taking up 50% of the row and the 3 textinput to collectively take up the rest of the 50%.

You can import `Dimensions` from `react-native` and do 
`const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;` 
and then use `maxWidth` to prevent the image from being too big

Here is the SnackExpo for my code. https://snack.expo.io/HJXemkUXM

Maybe you could do a quick sketch on paint or something to show us what you want where and how you want it to look.

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    maxWidth: ScreenWidth,
    paddingTop: 25,
  },
  image: {
    maxWidth: ScreenWidth*0.50,
    height: 200,
    // flex: 2/4,
    // resizeMode: 'contain',
    // width: 800,
    // height: 800,
  },
  floatLabelTextInput: {
    // flex: 2/4,
    // padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: I added a mock up of my proposed layout to the question, more of a column layout than row. I can get the Image proportions correct, but `FloatLabelTextInput` doesn't seem to accept a `height` property when I add it to the style.

Comment: I managed to get the layout corrected by using your suggestion of removing flex from the `floatLabelTextInput` and using ScreenWidth to size the Image. Seems a better approach including what @Ian Mundy mentioned about `floatLabelTextInput` taking flex as 1 in all cases.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution from what I gave you! And now I know that floatLabelTextInput exists!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [the source](https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-floating-label-text-input/blob/master/index.js#L109) of react-native-floating-label-test-input applies the style props you're passing in to the `TextInput` it maintains which is going to behave differently than if the flex property had been applied to the outer container `View`.

I'm guessing that you don't actually want the `TextInput` to be that size though since it would result in the inputs being identically sized to the image. If I were working on this, I would probably give my inputs a fixed height and then apply a flex style to the Image. Or If I knew the size of the image I may also give it a fixed size.

Edit: It's also worth noting that the `View` container from that package [does have flex: 1 set](https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-floating-label-text-input/blob/master/index.js#L189) which is going to cause some headaches probably unless you nest them in your own `View` where you control the `height` and/or `flex`.

Comment: I think you have identified the main problem - specifically, that the `flex` property in the `FloatLabelTextInput` package is set to 1.

Comment: I've cracked it for the Image layout, but as you pointed out with `FloatLabelTextInput` the heights are too large. I did try setting an explicit `height: '40'` on each in the seylt definition but this has no effect on the input heights. Any ideas on that?